# How to make col-xs-6 under instead of beside each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using 3 col-xs-6 for my form fields but I'm not getting the result I want.

I want to achieve this:

```
| col-xs-6 | 
| col-xs-6 |
| col-xs-6 |
```

but instead I see this

```
| col-xs-6 | col-xs-6 |
| col-xs-6 |
```

I know this is the way it works but I want to achieve the first result. I've tried applying row to each of the col-xs-6s but that didn't work.

This is my html

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <h1>Form</h1>

   <form class="top20" ng-submit="vm.exportForm()" name="vm.exportForm" novalidate>
       <formly-form model="vm.exportModel" fields="vm.exportFields" form="vm.exportForm"></formly-form>
   </form>
</div>
```

and this is how I structure the formly form in the controller

```
vm.exportFields = [
    {
        className: 'col-xs-6',
        key: 'field1',
        type: 'select2',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'Field1',
            valueProp: 'subCode',
            labelProp: 'description',
            options: []
        }
    },
    {
        className: 'col-xs-6',
        key: 'field2',
        type: 'select2',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'Field2',
            valueProp: 'subCode',
            labelProp: 'description',
            options: []
        }
    },
    {
        className: 'col-xs-6',
        key: 'field3',
        type: 'select2',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'Field3',
            valueProp: 'subCode',
            labelProp: 'description',
            options: []
        }
    }
];
```

**Update**

What I've decided to do is make my fields `col-xs-12` and wrap them in a `<div class="col-xs-6"></div>` instead. Looks like I expected it to be. Thanks guys.

Comment: You can use `col-xs-12` instead to get the result.

Comment: you need to wrap them in `row`

Comment: @AryanTwanju The reason I used col-xs-6 is the width of the field. col-xs-12 makes fields really wide.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk Check the answer.

Comment: Each row has 12 spaces, so if your elements are smaller than that, they will fill a row. Use a combination of row, to wrap items in a row, and col-offset to specify how to offset you col-6 div

Comment: Bootstrap has a [utility class called `w-100`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#column-breaks) that forces column breaks. Might be of help.

Comment: check my answer below. that might work for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want them in its own line, wrap it inside a `.row`:

```
.row
  | col-xs-6 |
.row
  | col-xs-6 |
.row
  | col-xs-6 |
```

In complex ways, you can try using `.push` and `.pull` classes, along with `.col-offset` classes.

Comment: I've tried  className: 'col-xs-6 row' for each of the fields but that just brings them closer to each other, not separates them. Not sure whether that's formly form or my code.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk No no. `.row` should be the parent. It should not be added as another class. `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"></div></div>`

Comment: I've also tried wrapping my <form> in <div class="row"></div> but that didn't work. I'm not entirely sure where to place it.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk Check my previous comment again, please. `:D` Just the `.col-xs-6` alone.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t want **col-xs-6**... you want **col-xs-12** (100% width). The problem you are having is that you have 3 columns with 50% width, so 2 of them are side by  side and the third one is below of the first two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind all the `col-xs-6` inside the `row` class. Then it will be in that form.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

 <!-- Start of row  -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      My Text
    </div>
   </div>
  <!-- End of row  -->
  
  <!-- Start of row  -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      My Text
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <!-- Start of row  -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      My Text
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- End of row  -->
   
 </div>
```

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk i have updated the code snippet making it more readable. All you need to do is wrap each div with`.col-xs-6` classes inside a div with `.row` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your code this way.

```
vm.exportFields = [
    {
        className: 'col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3',
        key: 'field1',
        type: 'select2',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'Field1',
            valueProp: 'subCode',
            labelProp: 'description',
            options: []
        }
    },
    {
        className: 'col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3',
        key: 'field2',
        type: 'select2',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'Field2',
            valueProp: 'subCode',
            labelProp: 'description',
            options: []
        }
    },
    {
        className: 'col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3',
        key: 'field3',
        type: 'select2',
        templateOptions: {
            label: 'Field3',
            valueProp: 'subCode',
            labelProp: 'description',
            options: []
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: Yes and no. col-xs-offset-3 makes them all move to the middle of the screen. Yes, they are on top of each other now but with a col-xs-3 gap on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 " style="background-color:lavender;">col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 " style="background-`color:lavenderblush`;">col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 " style="background-color:lavender;">col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```